# Arcpy fails to refresh page layout after changing the definitionQuery of a layer

Tags: arcpy, data-frame

I am trying to automate an export of map images in JPEG format. My script creates the map and exports it, but the export does not honor the changes made to the definitionQuery of the layer in the map (only one layer currently). The code is:

```
for i in range(int(minuid),int(maxuid)+1):
    layer.definitionQuery='UID > {}'.format(int(i))
    dtFrame.scale=28000
    newExtent = dtFrame.extent
    newExtent.XMin=12345.678
    newExtent.XMax=12345.678
    newExtent.YMin=12345.678
    newExtent.YMax=12345.678
    dtFrame.extent = newExtent
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    mapdoc.save()
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,('UID','attr1'),where_clause=None,sql_clause=None) as rq:
        for point1 in rq:
            nameval=point1 [1]
            uidval= point1 [0]    
            defq='UID = '+str(int(uidval))
            defq = unicode(defq,"utf-8")
            layer.definitionQuery = defq
            mapdoc.activeView = dtFrame
            mapdoc.activeView=dtFrame.name
            mapdoc.save()
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
            pictype="mapexport"
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mapdoc, r"location/"+nameval+str(int(uidval))+" "+pictype)
```

Comment: The numbers and paths are not the actual ones used!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. The problem is that somehow the dtFrame and layer variables loose their ability to pass any property back to the map if changed once. So after the first time the definition query is changed, any additional tries to change the definition query again will fail to pass the property back to the map. The solution is simply to recall both the data frame and layer and reset the variables. Then the definition query can be set once more.

Comment: That is not the solution.  The solution is to simplify the code and avoid using embedded loops that change the definition query in both loops.  You have written code that is overly complicated.

Comment: Actually I tried your solution. Didn't work. I embeded the searchcursor exactly to have more control on this. Even if I try to iterate through the features of the layer without the for loop (simply getting the UID from the table's attributes) and then setting the definition query using this UID from the attibutes of the layer doesn't change the page layout.

Comment: What is the code you used to "recall both the data frame and layer and reset the variables"?  Your post is not an answer without showing the code that accomplishes that.  Without that I can't figure out what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line that converts defq to unicode.  I do not think it is needed.

Also you are changing the definition query on a layer that at the same time is using a cursor based on a different definition query.  That will screw up the cursor.  Embedded loops almost always cause problems when the same layer is being changed in both loops.  Load the Searchcursor to a list using list comprehension so that the cursor is completed before you do the for loop, then loop through the list instead.

```
rq = [[row[0:]] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,('UID','attr1'))]
```

Also, do you realize that minuid will be excluded from the set of features being processed?  If it supposed to be included you need to change the second line to:

```
layer.definitionQuery='UID >= {}'.format(int(i))
```

I do not really think you should use the outer for loop at all.  I think you will repeatedly create maps for the same IDs (which makes no sense to me).  If that is intentional explain why you want to do that.  If you do not want to make multiple copies of maps for each uid, you should just run through a list comprehension of a cursor based on the definition query:

```
layer.definitionQuery='UID >= {0} AND UID <= {1}'.format(minuid, maxuid)
```